# Tomcat.8.5.15 is not accepting "\" in URI and throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: tomcat, uri

When i use "\" as path delimiter in URI ,i am getting a illegalargumentexception in tomcat 8.5.15.Below is the error message:-

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:472)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

To bypass this issue i tried to add

```
 org.apache.catalina.connector. CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
```

in catalina.properties,still i am not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you can set `requestTargetAllow` option. Just uncomment the last line in your file.

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

\ is used as for escape sequence in many programming languages, including Java.

replace every "\" to double backslash or you can use "/".

Answer (score 0):

> When i use "" as path delimiter in URI ,i am getting a illegalargumentexception in tomcat 8.5.15.Below is the error message:

Let's look at the error message

> Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Without browsing through those RFCs and trying to determine the details of valid characters etc in every detail: Which part of the error message would you like us to explain?

Just looking [at the definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) of a path in a URI *only* mentions "/" as a path separator. And no, I'm not even claiming to link to the relevant section of that RFC: Just the error message alone make me think that it might be simpler to revert your use of "" as path separator than to work around all future problems.

If you manage to convince Tomcat right now that it accepts nonstandard characters, future reverse-proxies, or caching proxies, or other mid-stream components might not, and you'd generate a heap of upcoming maintenance. Change it at the root and stop doing what you're doing right now.

And if you've copied/pasted that ALLOW_BACKSLASH setting to the question, it contains a superfluous space: If that's actually in your configuration, then you've not configured what you intended to configure. I'd still strongly arguing about fixing it on that level.

Answer (score -2):

I can suggest you to downgrade **Tomcat version to 8.5.6**.